# Protractor : Wait for an asyncronous service call in OnInit method of a component to test a value

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm facing a problem with protractor in my Angular2+ app trying to test some Hello World service which provide a value for a H1 tag. When i put plain text in H1 tag i can test it and it work. But when i use asyncronous serivce to provide a value to H1 tag in onInit, test fail.

I've tried `browser.sleep(5000)` , `browser.wait(ExpectedCondition ...)` , but nothing worked.

And many other thing like playing with `setTimeout` and `promise`, but nothing worked.

Here is the non asyncronous test :

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';

describe('poc-pn App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
  });
});

// navigateTo = browser.get()

// getParagraphText() = element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText();
```

Comment: Please give the error message

Comment: I didn't keep every wrong code but it was something like expecting value to be 'Hello World !' but was ''  (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with await, like this:

```
it('should display welcome message', () => {
    await page.navigateTo();
    expect(await page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
});
```

Comment: Don't think that's the solution, don't know how but browser.get isn't an async function even add the async keyword doesn't change something.